# How do i update a matplotlib plot legend/label dynamically?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, legend

I want to update the "label"/legend parameter dynamically. It will be an integer variable coming from a function. I want the label to change every time that value in the function changes.

so i want it to say **alpha = some int variable**

```
    plt.plot(vals, smpl_sz, 'b', marker = 'o', label='alpha='**some value that updates**)
    plt.plot(val2, smpl_sz2, 'g', marker = 'o', label = 'alpha='**some value that updates** )
    plt.title('Power vs Sample Size')
    plt.xlabel('Power')
    plt.ylabel('Sample Size')
    plt.legend(loc = "lower right")
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `label=f'alpha={somevaluethatupdates:.0f}`?

Comment: wont let me accept your answer but this was what i was looking for thanks